# Stop method being accessed directly in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, url-routing

I have a method, for example UserController@getRead to read all or a specific users details. I have a route `Route::controller('user', 'UserController');` so that within any other method I can get information about a user using:

```
$request = Request::create('user/read/'.$userId, 'GET');
$user = json_decode(Route::dispatch($request)->getContent());
```

However it also means I can browse to 'user/read/1' and get all the information on user 1. This is obviously a security flaw and needs plugging. How can I access the read method of UserController within the application, but not directly by browsing to user/read?

Comment: Does this create an AJAX request?

Comment: No, `Request::ajax()` returns false whether accessed internally with Request, or through the browser directly.

Comment: How about `Request::isJson()` or `Request::wantsJson()`? Basically, you make a filter and apply it to this route that check one of those `Request::something()` parameters, and if true ... else ...

Comment: `Request::path()` holds the original path that the user browsed to, so I can test that. Thanks for giving me the inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request::path()` to get the path entered into the browser, and then test to see if it's `user/read`. If it is abort, otherwise continue. This is my code for the specific instance:

```
if (stripos(Request::path(), 'user/read') !== false)
{
    App::abort(403, 'No direct access allowed');
}
```